# count match value two matrix using bsxfun

Tags: matlab, matrix, bsxfun

I use `c=bsxfun(@eq,b,a)` to compare value of two matrix. but I find it difficult to count un-match values. for example, I use this code

```
a = [1 2 3 4 7 6; ...
     3 2 4 6 7 2 ];
b = [1 3 2 4 5 7; ...
     3 4 5 6 7 2; ...
     2 3 4 5 6 6];
for i = 1:size(a,1)
    c= bsxfun(@eq,a(i,:),b)
    match = sum(c')
end
```

and result

```
 c =
   1     0     0     1     0     0
   0     0     0     0     1     0
   0     0     0     0     0     1

 match =
   2     1     1

c =
   0     0     0     0     0     0
   1     0     0     1     1     1
   0     0     1     0     0     0

match =
   0     4     1
```

I want to save value first match matrix with second match. for example

```
total_match = 
   2 5 2
```

Do you have any suggestion ? thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for loop

```
match = bsxfun( @eq, permute( a, [1 3 2]), permute( b, [3 1 2] ) ); % result in 2x3x6 boolean
match = sum( match, 3 ); % sum matches across rows of a--b
total_match = sum( match, 1 );
```

PS
[It is best not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: @user2203941 - if this answer works for you, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.

Comment: but how if i want a is mxn matric and b is pxn matric?

Comment: @user2203941 - have you tired the code on your example? should work for any `m` and `p`, as long as the number of column is identical.